# ¿QUE ESTOY HACIENDO MAL EN EL TRIGGER?

Tags: mysql, trigger

Estoy creando un trigger para insertar datos en una tabla, pero al momento de ejecutar el archivo me muestra el siguiente mensaje:

> Error de SQL(1064): You have an error in you SQL syntax; Check the manual that corresponds to your MYSQL server version for the right sintax to use near '' at line 4;

No me dice mucho tampoco, así que no encuentro el motivo del error del trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER ACUERDOSCOMERCIAL_IA AFTER INSERT ON ACUERDOS FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    DECLARE CLAVE_VENDEDOR VARCHAR(8);
    DECLARE NOMBRE VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE PRECIOLISTA INT;

    IF NEW.TIPODOCUMENTO LIKE 'Factura' THEN 
     //CASE A
    ELSE
     //CASE B
    END IF;     
END;
```

¿Estaré declarando mal mis variables?

Comment: Ese es todo el código de tu trigger?

Comment: @BetaM si lo que esta dentro del if y else solo es la inserción a la tabla donde quiero que vayan estos datos

Comment: No sé si considerarlo como duplicado, pero la respuesta está en [Es necesario escribir DELIMITER para crear un trigger o para crear un procedimiento almacenado?](/questions/286204/)

Comment: @padaleiana Ya se los agregue pero aun así sigue sin poder ejecutar el trigger